# Apple Mail App Unread Email Button unhighlighted

Tags: mail.app, email

[image: Apple Mail Unhread Emails Button]

After migrating to a new macbook pro using Time machine, my 'Unread Emails' button in the Apple Mail.app is now (one on the bottom right) permanently disabled/un-highlighted/unuseable, even when I have plenty of unread emails in my inbox. Anyone know how to fix this or get it working again?